# Uploading files to amazon s3 from vendors

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wanna upload the iamges not only to server, but also to amazon s3. How can I do that?

I am using CKEditor wysiwyg. I installed it through composer and it's places inside vendors folder.

To connect with amazon s3 I'm using another bundle.

Uploading files works from a controller (I use service that connects with the bundle, which in turns connects with amazon s3).

But how can I do that from the level of the vendors folder, so that I can upload images from wysiwyg?

Thanks a lot!